# MySQL SELECT Statement, changing one value within a column

Tags: mysql

I'm running a report using SELECT and want to change all NULL values within a column to a specific value in the output. All non-null values should remain untouched.

The null values exist because of an outer join. The column does not exist in all tables, but in the output I want a single value to appear instead of NULL.

Here is non-working SQL to illustrate what I am trying to do.

SELECT number, letter
IF number = null THEN 0
END IF
FROM...
and so on.

Comment: See the `IFNULL` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT number, letter, ifnull(number,0) 
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out isNull statement, it might help

> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 
        letter
        , IF(number is null, 0, number) as number
FROM .....